# Implementing a Type Defined in a Template Argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc, types

This code runs on Visual Studio 2013 but not on gcc 4.9.2:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(){
    T::value_type bar('a');

    cout << bar << endl;
}

int main() {
    foo<string>();

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that Visual Studio 2013 deduces type to allow me to implement types defined in template arguments whereas [gcc 4.9.2 does not](http://ideone.com/1iCi0G).

Is there a workaround for this that would allow this behavior in gcc?

Comment: what is the error you are getting, this will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `T::value_type` names a type so that it knows how to parse the declaration.

```
typename T::value_type bar('a');
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more details on where and why you need to do this.